# Discord JS version 14 - Temporary Voice channels

Tags: discord, permissions, discord.js, roles, voice

I'm developing a discord bot (using the version 14) about temporary voice channels. The problem that I have is that I don't know how to **clone the category roles and permissions to the new channel that I've just created**.

Can someone help me? I've the following code and it's working besides that.

```
const { Events, ChannelType, Collection, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, PermissionFlagsBits, PermissionOverwrites, Permissions  } = require('discord.js');

let voiceManager = new Collection();

module.exports = {
    name: Events.VoiceStateUpdate,
    async execute(oldState, newState) {
    
    const { member, guild } = oldState;
    const newChannel = newState.channel;
    const oldChannel = oldState.channel;
  
    if (oldChannel !== newChannel && newChannel && newChannel.id === '882632556372176937') {
  
      const sourceCategory = newChannel.parent;
  
      const voiceChannel = await guild.channels.create({
        name: "Your Mom's Room",
        type: ChannelType.GuildVoice,
        parent: newChannel.parent,
        permissionOverwrites: [
          //O HOST
          {
            id: member.id,
            allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.Connect, PermissionFlagsBits.ReadMessageHistory],
            deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.ManageChannels],
          },
          // @EVERYONE
          {
            id: guild.id,
            allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel, PermissionFlagsBits.Connect],
          },
        ],  
        userLimit: '5',
        bitrate: 96000
      })
```

Comment: I'd be happy to look into it but I still haven't received any response or feedback on my previous response.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
permissionOverwrites: [
          //O HOST
          {
            id: member.id,
            allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.Connect, PermissionFlagsBits.ReadMessageHistory],
            deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.ManageChannels],
          },
          // @EVERYONE
          {
            id: guild.id,
            allow: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel, PermissionFlagsBits.Connect],
          },
        ],
```

changed to

```
permissionOverwrites: newState.channel.parent.permissionOverwrites.cache
```

Hope this helps you